# Making the react native app stripe to live mode

Tags: react-native, stripe-payments

I am working on react native app and the app is using the test mode stripe and I am also making the test stripe to live,

I have a simple question, Is there anything I have to change while making the stripe to live mode,

1. I changed the switch to live in the stripe dashboard.
2. I changed the key and secret in app and server.

Do I also have to change something else?

And what are these and why and how are they used and where can I find these in the dashboard.

```
merchantIdentifier: 'merchant.com.stripe.react.native',
urlScheme: 'stripe-example',
```

Answer (score 1):

The testmode toggle in the Stripe dashboard has no impact on what mode your integration is operating in, it only changes what data you're viewing in the dashboard. When the toggle is on, the Stripe dashboard will display the testmode data for your account, and when it is off you will see livemode data.

The secret and publishable key that you provide dictate what mode your integration will operate in, and are likely the only values that you need to change.  [source](https://stripe.com/docs/libraries/react-native#:%7E:text=Use%20your%20API%20keys%20for%20test%20mode%20while%20you%20test%20and%20develop%2C%20and%20your%20live%20mode%20keys%20when%20you%20publish%20your%20app.)

The `merchantIdentifier` is not a value that you find, but rather is one that you set when you're registering for an Apple Merchant ID. It is an optional parameter that you can omit if you're not planning to accept Apple Pay payments. [source](https://stripe.com/docs/apple-pay?platform=react-native#merchantid)

`urlScheme` is an optional parameter that is only needed if you're planning to manually handle the 3DS authentication flow rather than rely on the pre-built functionality that Stripe provides. [source](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/3d-secure?platform=react-native#when-to-use-3d-secure)

Comment: Thank you i have also found some info about the merchant identifier (used for apple pay),
https://stripe.com/docs/apple-pay?platform=react-native, I will ask you some question if I need them.

Comment: I just want to confirm that, do I also need to change something else to make the stripe live, I changed the keys.

Comment: Changing the keys is the primary driver, are you not seeing your requests being made against livemode after changing the keys, or do you see something else to suggest that changing the keys wasn't enough to toggle the mode of operation for your integration?